# Import csv into mysql database - error

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I created a php script wihic i will put into cron jobs and should be executed at midnight, but this is not a issue. Issue is when cron runs my code it deletes all records from database but DOES NOT insert new recordes from CSV file. Any hint?

PHP code is below:

```
<?php 

# I run this script from a cron job every night to update 
# the mysql database I use with my employee web site 
# so it matches my local database every day.  Feel free to 
# modify it to meet your specific needs.  If you find it 
# usefull, drop me an email and let me know. 

# edit the follow six items to use the script 

# first connect to your mysql database 
# i have my connection settings in a diferent file 
# so i just include that file in all my scripts 
include("db.php"); 

# assign the tables that you want to import to to the table array 
$table = array( 
                'table1', 
                'table2', 
                'table3', 
                'table4', 
                'table5', 
        ); 

# if the first row of your csv file contains column headings: 
# $columnheadings=1 
# if the first row does not contain column headings and should be imported: 
# $columnheadings=0 
$columnheadings = 0; 

# contains the email address you want the results sent to 
$emailaddress = "user@domain.com"; 

# contains the subject you want the message to have 
$subject = "Enter Subject Here"; 

# contains the email address that will show in the from line 
$emailfrom = "user@domain.com"; 

# perform the required operations for every table listed in the table array 
foreach ($table as $tablename) { 

    # empty the table of its current records 
    $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE `$tablename`"; 
    mysql_query($deleterecords); 

    # intialize your counters for successful and failed record imports 
    $pass = 0; 
    $fail = 0; 

    # the csv file needs to be the same name as the table, 
    # comma seperated with the columns in the same order as the table, 
    # and in the same dir as this script 
    $filecontents = file ("$tablename.csv"); # .csv is added to the table name to get the name of the csv file 

    # every record in the csv file will be inserted into the table unless an error occurs with that record 
    for($i=$columnheadings; $i<sizeof($filecontents); $i++) { 
        $insertrecord = "Insert Into `$tablename` Values ($filecontents[$i])"; 
        mysql_query($insertrecord); 
        if(mysql_error()) { 
            $fail += 1;     # increments if there was an error importing the record 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $pass += 1;        # increments if the record was successfully imported 
        } 
    } 

    # adds a line to the email message we will send stating how many records were imported 
    # and how many records failed for each table 
    $message .= "Table $tablename: Success=$pass  Failure=$fail \n"; 
} 

# set to the date and time the script was run 
$runtime = (date("d M Y H:i")); 

# add the run time to the body of the email message 
$message .= "\nTime of the message: $runtime (server time zone)\n\n"; 

# Send the email message 
mail($emailaddress, $subject, $message, "From: '$emailfrom'"); 

?>
```

Comment: Is the CSV file in the same directory as this script? If not, you will need to provide the full path to the CSV file. Additionally I would add an error condition if the file could not be opened.

Comment: For debugging you should log at least one of the error's that may happen.

Comment: Yes, csv is in same directory, there is no errors just blank page when i run file directly from browser

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not check for the existance of the file - so, what if its not where you're thinking its looking? Depending on how you run this from cron, it may run from a different directory than if you ran it from the web.

Comment: But that hasnt checked your code is looking in the folder, as your code has not checked what folder its in, if run from cron it could be running from your home directory not the web directory.. Also you would get a blank page from the web as theres no output other than a mail, which may have failed for some reason... why not write to a file to check in case.. or even screen as a check. (cron usually mails by default any output to the user)

Comment: OK, but anyway my script have error becouse does not insert data into mysql table, that is a big probem

Comment: Which it wont, because if it finds no file to read, your array is empty, so no data is loaded!

Comment: But all csv files are uploaded to webhost, in same directory where script is located. That is a problem. Or i dont understand what you talking about :)

Comment: depends if the file is readable by the user the job runs as (be it from web or cron), it depends if the file is altered by the upload, when done by cron, as I said cron will almost certainly run the file from a different directory so "myfile.csv" is going to be looked for in another directory....  I guess you get no success/fail counts because its not found any lines to process.

Comment: I guess you get no success/fail counts because its not found any lines to process - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Add output to your file so it can be seen to run irrelevant of mail sending. So, in your for loop for the table, output the table, output "deleting previous", check for file existance and output "found file $tablename.csv", read file, output "found ".sizeof($filecontents)."lines" .. etc.. on fail of the mssql, output the errror!

Comment: Now i recieve email from my webhost. This is message:Table tabela1: Success=0  Failure=3 

Time of the message: 21 Jun 2012 08:32 (server time zone) So there is a error nothing is imported, but why????

Comment: Right so if tailed to load 3 lines in.. Make it output the mysql error.. chances are, you have a mismatch of columns or it didnt like the data.

Comment: Also, for your sanity checking - when starting out on this, Id have set the query text to display on screen so I could visually see what it was trying to do

Comment: Trust me man I am to tired to code this any more, do you have any code suggestion? What to check:) I putted echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";, but nothing happens, no error codes

Comment: echo? you're tired?? dont go there.. $link? Is that your db connection?? you need to stop rushing, and start thinking it through.. it shouldnt have taken you this many comments on here to establish if it was reading a file, and if it was erroring on any lines..

Answer (score 0):

Whats the schema of table, and what you are getting in `$message` at the end? are you getting all rows as failed?

**Added:**

As all rows are failing, means there is some problem in insert statement or probably schema mismatch between csv and target table. try this

```
    # and in the same dir as this script 
    $filecontents = file ("tablename.csv"); # .csv is added to the table name to get the name of the csv file 

    # every record in the csv file will be inserted into the table unless an error occurs with that record 
    for($i=$columnheadings; $i<sizeof($filecontents); $i++) { 
        $insertrecord = "Insert Into `$tablename` Values ($filecontents[$i])"; 
        mysql_query($insertrecord); 
        if(mysql_error()) { 
            $fail += 1;     # increments if there was an error importing the record
             //this is include exact error in email, and will help you to identify the
             //problem very easily.
             $message .= mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $pass += 1;        # increments if the record was successfully imported 
        } 
    }
```

try this and let me know with your finding?

Comment: I dont recieve any errors at all. Just all data are erased from tabel

Comment: what you are getting in email? as at the end of script you are sending email, and it will let you know how many rows passed and how many failed?

Comment: I dont recieve any messages from file, only deleting part works ;(

Comment: Hello Ummar, i recieved message, all rows fails ;(